# How to set the proper Python version when creating a virtual environment using virtualenv on windows?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I want to use python 2.7 instead of python 3, which is used by default (note that I have them both installed on my computer already).
So I tried what I saw should be the right thing to do, that is:

```
python -m virtualenv my_env -p "\Program Files (x86)\Python27\pythonw.exe"
```

and I receive the following message:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter \Program Files (x86)\Python27\pythonw.exe
```

That doesn't look so much like an error to me, but yet, no environment is created. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: this is a duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv

Comment: obligatory: please don't use python 2.7 unless you have a very good reason to use it. also, 99% of the time, you won't. Why do you want to use python 2.7? (Note that python 2 has been officially end-of-lifed)

Comment: The path looks incomplete. You should probably specify `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\pythonw.exe"` (assuming this is indeed on the `C:` drive).

Comment: Why just dont use miniconda? It's much easier.

Comment: It's not a matter of path, the '\' character takes the path back to the C: drive already. Otherwise, if I want to use python 2.7, it is only for having some outdated code that I downloaded to run.